# Swagger-ui local setup issue

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to do local setup of swagger-ui, i am following this link [Swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui)  and following the instruction given in how to use it, i have download its zip file, installed nodejs package and tried to run the following commands mentioned there in the link,

```
1. npm Install 
2. gulp
```

but as i run npm install it gives me error which is[image: Error Screen Shot 1][ Error Screen Shot 1 ]

can you guide me how i can complete swagger-ui local environment setup.
by following above mentioned link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is really no reason to download and rebuild swagger-ui.  It's probably easiest to grab one of the releases and run it in an http server:

1. Download https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/archive/v2.1.4.zip
2. unzip v2.1.4.zip
3. cd swagger-ui-2.1.4\dist
4. http-server .

This assumes you have installed http-server:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

then you can access swagger-ui at http://localhost:8080

Comment: thanks @fehguy: that is great it worked perfectly as i wanted to do.
i have one more little thing to ask, could i ask here in comments or post a next question for it.

Comment: Sure I'd post a new question and tag it with swagger

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Docker I found [this pre-built image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sjeandeaux/docker-swagger-ui/) works well:

```
docker run -d --name swagguer-ui -p 8888:8888 sjeandeaux/docker-swagger-ui
```

Or with your own default API URL:

```
docker run -d --name swagger-ui -p 8888:8888 -e "API_URL=YOUR_URL" sjeandeaux/docker-swagger-ui
```